# MATLAB: converting 3d plane into 3d matrix pixel locations

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, plane, orthogonal

I am trying to get a slice of an elongated object in a 3d matrix (227x297x187 binary) that is orthogonal to its orientation..i.e. output image would be a 2d cross-section.

I was thinking the best way to do this would be to find a vector giving the orientation at some point on the object (so for a cross-section at the 40th slice I get the location of centroids at the 30th and 50th slices and find the vector between them), then get a list of pixels corresponding to a plane orthogonal to that vector at the desired slice (along centroid of object at 40th slice), and then retrieve the values in the matrix corresponding to those locations. Assuming the code I have attached finds the plane, I can plot it with surf() but don't know how to translate that into pixel locations in the matrix to generate the values for the 2d cross-section.

```
startslice=30;
endslice=50;

startnums=bwconncomp(binMATRIX(:,:,startslice));
startnums=regionprops(startnums,'Centroid');

endnums=bwconncomp(binMATRIX(:,:,endslice));
endnums=regionprops(endnums2,'Centroid');

midnums3=bwconncomp(binMATRIX(:,:,(startslice+(endslice-startslice)/2)));
midnums3=regionprops(midnums,'Centroid');

startstuff=[startslice, startnums.Centroid];
endstuff=[endslice, endnums.Centroid];
midstuff=[(startslice+(endslice-startslice)/2), midnums.Centroid];

nullstuff=null(endstuff-startstuff);
A=nullstuff(:,1);
B=nullstuff(:,2);
[x,y]=meshgrid(A,B);
z=1-x-y;
surf(x+midstuff(1),y+midstuff(2),z+midstuff(3))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? You didn't explain what it does, it's not runnable by us (missing inputs), you didn't explain where your difficulty is. As I understand, your question boils down to finding the countour of an area (since we're just looking at one slice) of ones/zeros in an array of zeros/ones. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: I edited the phrasing of the question...hope it helps. Basically I'm trying to get a cross-section of an object in 3d orthogonal to its orientation by finding the pixel locations of a plane that intersects a vector representing its orientation